# URL in JSON return as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to loop through some JSON but once it gets to the values that are url's, they are returning as undefined. Here's a simplified example of my JS

```
$.getJSON("https:../houston-locations.js", function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i, data){
      $("ul.mapList").append(
        '<li id="store-' + data.restaurant + '">'+
          '<div class="singleLocation">' +
            '<a href="' + data.directions + '" target="_blank"><button class="directions">DIRECTIONS</button></a>' +
            '<a href="' + data.url + '">Restaurant Details</a>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div></li>'
      )
  })
});
```

And my JSON:

```
{ "restaurant":31, "restaurantName":"Shenandoah", "address":"19075 IH 45 S Suite 480", "city":"Shenandoah", "state":"TX", "zip":77385, "phone":"(936) 271-9217", "directions":"https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Pei+Wei,+19075+I-45+%23480,+Shenandoah,+TX+77385/@30.1826863,-95.4533763,17z/", "url":"/texas/31-shenandoah"}
```

The two keys at the end, "directions" and "url" are the only ones that return as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Feels like it's all right. When you do `console.log(data.url)` are you getting your results?

Comment: I get undefined in the console for `console.log(data.url)`

Comment: You are using same variable again: `data`. Do something like `$.each(data, function(key, value){...});`

Comment: Almost certainly an issue with the "/" characters in those values.  You probably will have to encode those more than likely.  Research encodeURIComponent and see if that helps.

Comment: I would check the response from the API in the network tab to make sure all data has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
$.getJSON("https:../houston-locations.js", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, data) {
```

You are overwriting variable `data` in `function(i, data)`, consider to change it to `value` or something else.

Comment: Why would that effect only the two attributes 'directions' and 'url'?

Comment: Actually I don't know, other keys in data should be undefined too then. Anyway, changing `data` to `value` in `each` function would fix your problem.

Comment: I tried this and i'm still getting undefined for the two values.

Comment: Can you write `console.log(data)` just before your each function and put there a result?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
    $.getJSON( "ajax/ejemplo.json", function( data ) {
      var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "" + val + "" );
      });

      $( "", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("https:../houston-locations.js",function(data){
    console.log(data);
     $.each(data, function( key, value ){
        console.log(data.directions);
        console.log(data.url);
  });
    });
```

the right use of $.getSOn is as above

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be something so simple.. It was a cache issue so the new JSON data wasn't being loaded. I did however change the overwriting 'data' values. Thanks everyone!